# how to receive files with socket.io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, jsx

im building this project for fun its a messaging app with react and socket.io.

now the app is fully capable of sending text messages between the users however it's not sending files between the users if you choose a file it will appear in your chat but won't appear to the rest of the people in the chat and I think is might be a problem with the useEffect that is handling the received message but I'm not sure how to fix it and I've been trying to debug this for over a week now (the supported file types are pics, videos, and pdf files).

this is my backend code:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const cors = require('cors');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});


io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(`user connected: ${socket.id}`);

    socket.on("send_message", (data) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit("receive_message", data);
    })
})

server.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log(`app is running on port 3001`);
})
```

and this is the function in my frontend code inside the ChatWindow.jsx where the chatting is happening that is responsible for sending the files and storing them in the messages array so they get displayed (all messages get stored inside an array called messages and in the return statement the component maps over them to display the messages):

```
const handleFileChange = (event) => {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        if (file) {
          const newMessage = {
            type: 'file',
            who: 'sender',
            file: file,
            timestamp: new Date().getTime()
          };
          setMessages([...messages, newMessage]);

          socket.emit('send_message', newMessage);
          console.log("file emitted");
        }
    };
```

and this is the useEffect that handles the received messages:

```
useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
            const newMessage2 = {
                type: 'text',
                who: 'receiver',
                text: data.message,
                timestamp: new Date().getTime()
            };

            setMessages(prevMessages => [...prevMessages, newMessage2]);  
        })
    }, [socket])
```

if anyone can catch what is wrong with this code ill really appreciate the help.
also if you want to see the full code of this component to get a better idea of the structure here it is:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import SenderMessage from './SenderMessage.jsx';
import RecieverMessage from './RecieverMessage.jsx';
import FileMessage from '../file components/FileMessage.jsx';
import io from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3001");


function ChatWindow() {
    const fileInputRef = useRef(null);
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

    const messagesEndRef = useRef(null);

    const handleFileChange = (event) => {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        if (file) {
          const newMessage = {
            type: 'file',
            who: 'sender',
            file: file,
            timestamp: new Date().getTime()
          };
          setMessages([...messages, newMessage]);

          socket.emit('send_message', newMessage);
          console.log("file emitted");
        }
    };

    const handleButtonClick = () => {
        fileInputRef.current.click();
    };

    const SendMessage = () => {
        if (inputValue.trim() === '') {
            return;
        }

        const newMessage = {
            type: 'text',
            who: 'sender',
            text: inputValue,
            timestamp: new Date().getTime()
        };

        setMessages(prevMessages => [...prevMessages, newMessage]);

        socket.emit("send_message", {message: inputValue});

        setInputValue('');
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
            const newMessage2 = {
                type: 'text',
                who: 'receiver',
                text: data.message,
                timestamp: new Date().getTime()
            };

            setMessages(prevMessages => [...prevMessages, newMessage2]);  
        })
    }, [socket])

    useEffect(() => {
        messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }, [messages]);

    return (
        <div className="chat_window_cont">

            <div className="chat-messages">

                {messages.map((msg, index) => {
                    if (msg.who === 'sender') {
                        if (msg.type === 'text') {
                            return (
                                <SenderMessage text={msg.text} timestamp={msg.timestamp} key={index}/>
                            );
                        } else if (msg.type === 'file') {
                            return (
                                <FileMessage file={msg.file} timestamp={msg.timestamp} key={index} />
                            );
                        }  
                    } else if (msg.who === 'receiver') {
                        if (msg.type === 'text') {
                            return (
                                <RecieverMessage text={msg.text} timestamp={msg.timestamp} key={index}/>
                            );
                        } else if (msg.type === 'file') {
                            return (
                                <FileMessage file={msg.file} timestamp={msg.timestamp} key={index} />
                            );
                        }  
                    }
                     
                })}

                <div ref={messagesEndRef} /> </div>

            <div className='inputsCont'>

                <button onClick={handleButtonClick} className='attach_btn'><i className="fa-solid fa-paperclip attach_logo"></i></button>
                <input
                    type="file"
                    accept=".pdf, .doc, .docx, .ppt, .pptx, .xls, .xlsx, .txt, .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif, .mp4, .avi, .mov"
                    style={{ display: 'none' }}
                    ref={fileInputRef}
                    onChange={handleFileChange}
                />
                
                <input type="text" className='text_input' value={inputValue} onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
                 onKeyDown={(e) => {
                    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                        SendMessage();
                    }
                 }}
                />

                <button className='send_btn'  onClick={SendMessage}><i className="fa-solid fa-paper-plane send_logo"></i></button>
            </div>

        </div>
    );
}

export default ChatWindow;
```

i tried chatGPT be its responses were useless so i hope to get an answer here.
thanks :)

this is the current code and its working when it comes to sending and receiving text messages but not working when it comes to files, it only views the sent file in the sender chat but the receiver doesnt see the file that was sent.